# Why is_dir() function is not checking case sensitive in CPanel server

Tags: php, file, directory, cpanel

I tried this code in localserver, It works correcly if my directory is having that foldername already and it won't accept the same folder to create, but if I uploaded the part in server.

If the directory is having foldername with Alto and new folder I tried name with alto Its just created why is it.

If anyone knows the solution.
[image]

```
<?php
$folder_type=$_POST['folder_type'];
$folder_name=$_POST['folder_name'];
$images="images";
$path="../../".$folder_type."/".$folder_name;
if (!is_dir("../../".$folder_type."/".$folder_name)) { 
mkdir("../../".$folder_type."/".$folder_name); 
mkdir("../../".$folder_type."/".$folder_name."/".$images); 
$content = file_get_contents('../../default_code.php');
$fp = fopen($path . "/$folder_name.php","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp); 
} 
else
{
    echo "0";
}
chmod("../../".$folder_type."/".$folder_name, 0777);
?>
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot where it added same name folder but in lowercase on server? To show two folders, same name , one upper and one lowercase one.

Comment: See the question just now I added screenshot of Cpanel

Comment: You have removed the code now, please add your code to see where is the fault.

Comment: See now @AbhayMaurya

Comment: There can be a possibility that first folder name is AIto (using capital i not small L). You can make sure of that by creating a new folder name: test and try to create it again with Test, if problem persists then use the solution i gave for future cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rule out this condition at all. Please use `strtolower` when creating a directory. That means use this:

```
$folder_name=strtolower($_POST['folder_name']);
```

Like this in future, your all folders will be in lowercase and there would be no chance of contradiction.

*I hope it helps*

Answer (score 1):

I assume your development environment is running on a case insensitive filesystem (in windows, as the screenshot confirms), while the application is deployed to a case sensitive filesystem (usually on Linux).

This would explain the differences in behaviour between the two environments.

Edit: and the workaround would be to either lowercase or uppercase all created directories and perform the check for the same lower or upper case.

Comment: Okie then how can I do this with this environment

Comment: @KavyaShree, I edited and added a suggestion for a workaround